# Run symfony command on separate VM

Tags: symfony

I have an application running Symfony 5.2 on apache ubuntu 18.04 vm (vm1). Users are uploading assets to the application that are at first stored in filesystem. I then have a symfony command triggered on cronjob that will:

- read from fs and read from db
- manipulate assets using terminal commands
- upload to separate storage
- remove assets from filesystem and update db.

The command is quite heavy so I would like to run it on a separate vm to avoid impact on user experience. My question is how to best achieve this.

My current thinking is that I can

- Disable command on vm1
- Setup new vm (vm2) with same codebase. Trigger command with cronjob on vm2
- Somehow allow communication between vm1 and vm2 (i guess both in same private network)
- Somehow allow vm2 read/write access to fs on vm1 (could probably be done by setting up nfs on vm1 accessed by vm2)
- Somehow allow vm2 read/write access to mysql db on vm1 (i guess open port 3306 to vm2's private ip)

Is this the best way forward or does symfony have some support to better achieve this?

Comment: All this looks plausible. But as you haven't shared why that command need so much ressources, it's pretty difficult to tell you whether this might work or not

Comment: "manipulate assets" that I wrote means running some ffmpeg commands and uploading results to separate storage. The ffmpeg commands takes a lot of resources